# Generate class from plist

Tags: objective-c, class, plist, code-generation

I'm looking for a way to generate classes from plist. The idea is to generate plist from a JSON stream and have a static way to export classes from the plist files.

Do you have any way to do that ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you have and what you want as a result?

Comment: @rmaddy said it, please provide exactly what you need, how should it be generated, when should it be generated, why should it be generated.

Comment: First thank you for your reply. As I understand generating dynamically classes is pretty impossible to do due to compiled language. I would like to generate business classes aligned on a plist. For example, I have a User plist containing his name and address ; and I would like to generate an Objective-c class with the name and address property. Then I would be able to populate the class properties with my data ans easily convert from plist to objective-c code. I don't know if I'm clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), section "Adding Classes".
Of curse this is about generating classes at runtime.

If you talking about Source Code generation, have a look at [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/index.html) and [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/). Those are very powerful tools for code generation. We use them to generate Objective-C code. There already is a [grammar for JSON](https://gist.github.com/nightscape/629651). Of curse, there's a lot of stuff to learn.

Comment: Thank you. I found a tool that should do what I want : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/objectify/id435651677?mt=12. Just bought it.

Comment: Ah, now I got what you where heading for. Simply generating classes representing your JSON structures in code. ;)

Comment: Pretty easy to understand as you explained :) Apologize